# Relative pose between two tf::Transforms

Tags: ros, pose, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

how can I get the relative pose between two *tf::Transform*s? I know that *tf::TransformListener* can do this if you call *lookupTransform* with identical target- and source-frame, but with different target- and source-times, but how can I achieve this without any messages if I only have two *tf::Transform*s (each representing a different point in time) of an odometry-source for example?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12654/relative-pose-between-two-tf::transforms/) by [ph4nt0m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1315/ph4nt0m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically invert one and multiply the other.

`tf1.inverseTimes(tf2)` should do that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2017-08-18**:
Is it tf1 wrt tf2 or tf2 wrt tf1?